# Is it possible to add a hidden field to a callout MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I have multiple pins and callouts on my map view. When I press the details button I would like it go to details page. I want to add a hidden id to the callout so I know which details page to send the user to.

Is this possible / is there another way of doing this?

Here is my [Code](http://pastebin.com/CQkLun53) if it helps.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Your MKAnnotationView has a reference to the annotation which the view is generated from. This value is an object conforming to the MKAnnotation protocol, which you can use to find the information associated with the pin view.

Comment: but cant you only use setCoordinate: and
setTitle:?

Comment: it's an object conforming to a protocol. You should find the class you used conforming to the protocol (the object you used when calling [makView addAnnotation:yourAnnotation]).

Comment: Im sorry I dont quite understand. could you possibly show me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some great [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495419/mkannotation-simple-example), already on stackoverflow. The example and answer describe the mkannotation protocol. Apple's documentation for this is also very good. Here's apple's information on the [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), and apple's overall documentation for [mapkit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html).

Basically what you do is you create your own class, make sure it conforms to the protocol, and you're good.