# Simple marker clustering on apple map

Tags: ios, objective-c-category

Hello I want to do Pin point's clustering on apple map. What is the possible solutions of it.Now the apple map with one pin point is display on my screen. What is the code after it for Pin point's grouping. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform clustering on google map in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727993/how-to-perform-clustering-on-google-map-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

A possible (and successful, I'm using it at work) solution for clustering/displaying lots of points on a map is

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-data-on-maps

Comment: I already try it But it crashed my application when I create a object of "TBMapViewController" in another view controller and add "TBMapViewController's" object as [self.view addsubView tbMapViewController.view]. It leads crashed my application when I do  single click/tap on apple map. It works perfect when I do double click. I don't what is the exception or line that occurs the crash but I got a point something that "I again call a deallocated  viewcontroller object of apple map". What it the possible reason?

Comment: Exception -[CFString length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15417ee0

Comment: I got the solution of it
"Add the -fobjc-arc flag to any files for which you'd like to enable ARC, as described in the ARC "